# Perl selectall_array - retrieve all data from array of array ref

Tags: arrays, perl, dbi, arrayref

I am using `DBI` `selectall_array` to fetch all the data out of mysql. My query returns 1 columns for every row. But the `selectall_array` function returns an array of array ref for each row as listed below

```
$VAR1 = [
          '1.ptmp'
        ];
$VAR2 = [
          'e1.ptmp'
        ];
$VAR3 = [
          's2.ptmp'
        ];
$VAR4 = [
          'sw1.ptmp'
        ];
$VAR5 = [
          'w1.ptmp'
        ];
```

What I would like is a way to extract all the domains into a single array (no refs) or is there a DBI function which returns a full array of data without any references? I dont want to loop through all data or do `fetchrow_array` in a while loop. Looking for a single statement to do it all if possible?

Please see my code below:

```
my @mysqldata = $dbh->selectall_array('SELECT `domain` FROM dfs WHERE `id` IN ('.join(',',('?')x(scalar(@params))).')', {}, @params);
my @minus = array_minus( @all, @mysqldata );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dereference the arrayrefs into one big array in one line like this:

```
my @all = map {@$_} $dbh->selectall_array($sql);
```

The `map` block applies `@$_` to each row returned by `selectall_array`, which dereferences the arrayref.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are only extracting one column you can try the `selectcol_arrayref()` method - de-referencing the array inline.

```
my @mysqldata = @{ $dbh->selectcol_arrayref('SELECT `domain` FROM dfs WHERE `id` IN ('.join(',',('?')x(scalar(@params))).')', {}, @params) };
```

**UPDATE**

As ysth suggested in the comments, you can use a postfix operator in newer versions of Perl (v5.20.0 and later) to dereference the value returned by `selectcol_arrayref()` - as in the following.

```
$dbh->selectcol_arrayref('SELECT domain FROM dfs', undef, @params)->@*;
```

Comment: Or postfix dereference: `= $dbh->selectcol_arrayref(...)->@*;`.  Or just keep it as a reference.

Comment: Postfix dereference is a nice new feature, but note it only became available in experimentally `v5.20` and is now stable as of `v5.24`

Comment: @ysth: Thanks. I have updated my answer to include your suggestion.